# Properties defined with property() and @property

Tags: python, oop

I am now trying to properly learn Python, and I am really puzzled by existence of two ways to create object properties: using the `@property` decorator and the `property()` method. So both of the following are valid:

```
class MyClassAt:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._time = value

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self._time

    @time.setter
    def time(self, value):
        if value > 0:
            self._time = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Time should be positive')
```

and

```
class MyClassNoAt:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._time = value

    def get_time(self):
        return self._time

    def set_time(self, value):
        if value > 0:
            self._time = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Time should be positive')

    time = property(fget=get_time, fset=set_time)
```

Is there an agreement which one to use? What would a Pythonista choose?

Comment: Both are equivalent. First form is definitely more common.

Comment: The first form is preferable. In the second form you expose two additional methods, `set_time` and `get_time` which now are part of your public api, and having separate set and get methods defeats the purpose of properties.

Comment: `@property` is *exactly the same thing*, simply using the `property()` object as a decorator. Use the decorator form wherever possible.

Comment: Everyone says that the first form should be used. So there is an agreement and no "opinions". Still the question is voted to be closed as opinion-based. While I didn't ask "which you prefer" but "if there was an agreement". Anyway, thanks everyone for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Asking for reasons on why there are two syntaxes, and when to use one over the other is not opinion-based.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you have voted to close the question, but at the same time provided an answer, in the comment. Apparently there is a uniform agreement on this question, so why have you flagged it as "opinion-based"? Anyway, I appreciate your answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days (pre python 2.4), the decorator syntax (i.e. `@property`) didn't exist yet, so the only way to create decorated functions was to use your second method

```
time = property(fget=get_time, fset=set_time)
```

The [PEP that lead to decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318) gives many reasons for the motivation behind the newer syntax, but perhaps the most important is this one.

> The current method of applying a transformation to a function or
>   method places the actual transformation after the function body. For
>   large functions this separates a key component of the function's
>   behavior from the definition of the rest of the function's external
>   interface.

It's much clearer with the newer `@` syntax that a property exists by simply skimming through the code and looking at the method/property definitions.

Unfortunately, when they first added the new `@property` decorator, it only worked for decorating a *getter*.  If you had a *setter* or a *deleter* function, you still had to use the old syntax.

Luckily, in Python 2.6, they added the `getter`, `setter`, and `deleter` attributes to properties so you could use the new syntax for all of them.

These days, there's really no reason to ever use the old syntax for decorating functions and classes.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent, but the first one is preferred as many people find it more readable (while also not cluttering the code *and* the namespace).
The problem with the second method is that you are defining two methods that you will never use, and they remain in the class.

One would use the second method only if they have to support a very old Python version, which does not support decorators syntactic sugar. Function and method decorators were added in Python 2.4 (while class decorators only in version 2.6), so that is in almost all cases a problem of the past.