# Correct use of property()? Pycharm doesn't recognize property defined with property() instead of @property? How to generate many similar properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, pycharm

I am trying to figure out if my issue is a pycharm bug, or if I have not understood how to use `property()` correctly, or whether there is a more pythonic way to implement what I am trying to achieve. I do not have any formal programming training, so it's very possible I am just trying to go about this entirely wrong, and my searches haven't really clarified anything to me. I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004026/properties-defined-with-property-and-property) answer, which makes me think I am using `property` correctly, but in a much simpler situation, so I'm not sure if that still applies here. I recognize that there is quite a lot to this question, but it's how it all ties together which is causing me problems, so I don't know how to ask it in smaller more specific chunks.

General Aim: I have a class in which I want to make several properties that are all very similar, therefore I do not want to define each with an `@property` decorator.

In the code below, the `# PROBLEM: ...` is where PyCharm isn't recognising the property. This is what is making me unsure as to whether I am using `property()` correctly and is where my main question lies. Am I misusing `property()` somehow? Am I trying to do something fundamentally wrong (see below for more info on my intentions)? Or is it just a PyCharm bug, and this code is actually ok?

To further clarify my intentions overall intentions: I think in this example it looks like I should have `A` and `B` as subclasses of `Test`, but in my real code I don't want to clutter up `A` and `B` and they use very little from the `Test` instance. I mostly just want `A`, `B`, etc to be able check whether other properties exist, and very minimally use values from attributes of classes retrieved by those other properties. I am trying to keep my subclasses  (`A`, `B`, etc) as easy to read/modify for someone who doesn't know much python as possible (working in a lab where I expect other students to modify only certain aspects of the code, and not have to understand the rest).

Here is the minimal(ish) example of what I am talking about:

```
# Parent Class which has lots of things relevant to A, B, etc 
class PropClass:
    def __init__(self, test_class):
        self.test_class = test_class
        # some init possibly using something from test_class
        pass

# I want these subclasses to be as easy as possible to modify/write for non programmers
class A(PropClass):
    # some additional methods etc (possibly using self.test_class)
    pass

class B(PropClass):
    # some additional methods etc (possibly using self.test_class)
    pass

# I have many more of these


prop_dict = {
    'a': A,
    'b': B,
    # Many more
}

class Test:
    def prop(self, key):
        """Use this for 'prop' part of many different properties (only varying 'key')"""
        private_key = '_'+key
        if not getattr(self, private_key, None):
            setattr(self, private_key, prop_dict.get(key)(self))
        return getattr(self, private_key)

    a = property(my_partial(prop, 'a', arg_start=1))

    def test_method(self):
        print(self.a)  # PROBLEM: Pycharm highlights this and suggests creating a property for 'a', but I think it already exists

# I want these subclasses to be very easy to modify/create for non programmers 
class SubTest(Test):  # I want to be able to create subclasses with different combinations/additions of the possible properties I have
    b = property(my_partial(Test.prop, 'b', arg_start=1)) 

    def test_method(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)


##################################
# Not really part of the question, but just including for completeness (basically partial() but skipping over 'self')
def my_partial(func, *args, arg_start=0, **kwargs):
    """Similar to functools.partial but with more control over which args are replaced"""

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkwargs):
        new_kwargs = {**kwargs, **fkwargs}
        new_args = list(fargs[:arg_start])  # called args until fixed args at arg_start
        new_args.extend(args)  # Add fixed args
        new_args.extend(fargs[arg_start + len(args) - 1:])  # Add any remaining called args
        return func(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

    # To make it more similar to functools.partial
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.arg_start = arg_start  # Might as well store this
    newfunc.keywords = kwargs
    return newfunc
##################################
```

#### Edit:

Pretty sure there is a bug in PyCharm because the warning highlighting shows up even with the minimal code below, but I am still unsure about whether I am going about things in a reasonable way in the above code.

```
class Test:
    def func(self):
        return 1
    a_prop = property(func)

t = Test()
t.a_prop  # <<< PyCharm suggests to make this a function call, but it is definitely a property.
```